# I have a dataframe. I need to add an array [a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d,] in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame `df` , I have an array `arr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]`. I need to add this array to existing data frame `df`.

My code is as follows:

```
low_limit = 2011 
upper_limit = 2017 
arr = np.repeat(np.arange(low_limit,upper_limit),2) 
df = df.withColumn('arrayYear',F.array(F.lit(arr))).show()
```

I am getting this error Py4JJavaError:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit. : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016] at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:80)
```

Comment: My code is as followss                                                                                      
 low_limit   = 2011
upper_limit = 2017
 arr = np.repeat(np.arange(low_limit,upper_limit),2) 
 df = df.withColumn('arrayYear',F.array(F.lit(arr))).show()

Comment: I am getting this error                                                                                                      Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016]
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:80)

Comment: Hi @Jason Roy welcome to SF. A good approach for asking for help is to put your code into the description instead of in the comment area. I've pasted your comments into the description area and you can edit them if it is not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new rows to pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685609/add-new-rows-to-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: @JasonRoy, you can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question.

Comment: Should every row get `arr` as new element or should `arr` become the column itself?