# Filling Missing sales value with zero and calculate 3 month average in PySpark

Tags: date, apache-spark, pyspark, missing-data

I Want add missing values with zero sales and calculate 3 month average  in pyspark

```
My Input :
  product    specialty    date       sales
  A           pharma      1/3/2019    50
  A           pharma      1/4/2019    60
  A           pharma      1/5/2019    70
  A           pharma      1/8/2019    80
  A           ENT         1/8/2019    50
  A           ENT         1/9/2019    65
  A           ENT         1/11/2019   40

my output:
   product    specialty    date       sales    3month_avg_sales
   A           pharma      1/3/2019    50       16.67
   A           pharma      1/4/2019    60       36.67
   A           pharma      1/5/2019    70        60
   A           pharma      1/6/2019     0        43.33
   A           pharma      1/7/2019     0        23.33
   A           pharma      1/8/2019    80        26.67
   A           ENT         1/8/2019    50        16.67
   A           ENT         1/9/2019    65        38.33
   A           ENT         1/10/2019    0        38.33  
   A           ENT         1/11/2019   40        35
 



row = Row("Product", "specialty","Date", "Sales")
df = sc.parallelize([row("A","pharma", "1/3/2019", 50),row("A","pharma", "1/4/2019", 60),row("A", "pharma","01/05/2019", 70),row("A","pharma", "1/8/2019", 80),row("A","ENT", "1/8/2019", 50),row("A","ENT", "1/9/2019", 65),row("A","ENT", "1/11/2019", 40)]).toDF()
w = Window.partitionBy("product","specialty).orderBy("date")
df.withColumn("new_data_date", expr("add_months(data_date, 1)"))
df.withcolumn("sales",F.where(col("date") isin col("new_data_date")
 df=df.withColumn('index', (year('Date') - 2020) * 12 + month('Date')).withColumn('avg',sum('Sales').over(w) / 3)
```

I am struck adding where ever date value is missed with sales value is zero . And calculate 3month average .

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: Spark 2.4  version

Comment: Coud you kindly paste the code which generates your output, it seems the one you posted is not the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SparkSQL builtin functions [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/sql/index.html#transform) + [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/sql/index.html#sequence) to create the missing months and set their sales=0, use Window aggregate function to calculate required `end_date` and the final 3-month average sales. Below I divided the code into three steps for illustration purpose, you can merge them based on your own requirements.

**Note:** this assumed at most one record in each distinct month and all the date values have day=1, otherwise truncate the date to the *month* level using `F.trunc(F.to_date('date', 'd/M/yyyy'), "month")` and/or define the logic for duplicate entries.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('A', 'pharma', '1/3/2019', 50), ('A', 'pharma', '1/4/2019', 60), 
    ('A', 'pharma', '1/5/2019', 70), ('A', 'pharma', '1/8/2019', 80), 
    ('A', 'ENT', '1/8/2019', 50), ('A', 'ENT', '1/9/2019', 65),
    ('A', 'ENT', '1/11/2019', 40)
], ['product', 'specialty', 'date', 'sales'])

df = df.withColumn('date', F.to_date('date', 'd/M/yyyy'))
```

**Step-1:** set up WinSpec `w1` and use Window aggregate function [lead](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead) to find the next date over(w1), convert it to the previous months to set up date sequences:

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('product', 'specialty').orderBy('date')

df1 = df.withColumn('end_date', F.coalesce(F.add_months(F.lead('date').over(w1),-1),'date'))
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------+
|product|specialty|      date|sales|  end_date|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------+
|      A|      ENT|2019-08-01|   50|2019-08-01|
|      A|      ENT|2019-09-01|   65|2019-10-01|
|      A|      ENT|2019-11-01|   40|2019-11-01|
|      A|   pharma|2019-03-01|   50|2019-03-01|
|      A|   pharma|2019-04-01|   60|2019-04-01|
|      A|   pharma|2019-05-01|   70|2019-07-01|
|      A|   pharma|2019-08-01|   80|2019-08-01|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------+
```

**Step-2:** use `months_between(end_date, date)` to calculate # of months between two dates, and use transform function to iterate through `sequence(0, #months)`, create a named_struct with date=`add_months(date,i)` and sales=`IF(i=0,sales,0)`, use [inline_outer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/sql/index.html#inline_outer) to explode the array of structs:

```
df2 = df1.selectExpr("product", "specialty", """
       inline_outer(
         transform(
            sequence(0,int(months_between(end_date, date))),
            i -> (add_months(date,i) as date, IF(i=0,sales,0) as sales)
         )
       )
   """)
+-------+---------+----------+-----+
|product|specialty|      date|sales|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+
|      A|      ENT|2019-08-01|   50|
|      A|      ENT|2019-09-01|   65|
|      A|      ENT|2019-10-01|    0|
|      A|      ENT|2019-11-01|   40|
|      A|   pharma|2019-03-01|   50|
|      A|   pharma|2019-04-01|   60|
|      A|   pharma|2019-05-01|   70|
|      A|   pharma|2019-06-01|    0|
|      A|   pharma|2019-07-01|    0|
|      A|   pharma|2019-08-01|   80|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+
```

**Step-3:** use the following WinSpec `w2` and the aggregate function to calculate the average:

```
N = 3

w2 = Window.partitionBy('product', 'specialty').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-N+1,0)

df_new = df2.select("*", F.round(F.sum('sales').over(w2)/N,2).alias(f'{N}month_avg_sales'))
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------------+
|product|specialty|      date|sales|3month_avg_sales|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------------+
|      A|      ENT|2019-08-01|   50|           16.67|
|      A|      ENT|2019-09-01|   65|           38.33|
|      A|      ENT|2019-10-01|    0|           38.33|
|      A|      ENT|2019-11-01|   40|            35.0|
|      A|   pharma|2019-03-01|   50|           16.67|
|      A|   pharma|2019-04-01|   60|           36.67|
|      A|   pharma|2019-05-01|   70|            60.0|
|      A|   pharma|2019-06-01|    0|           43.33|
|      A|   pharma|2019-07-01|    0|           23.33|
|      A|   pharma|2019-08-01|   80|           26.67|
+-------+---------+----------+-----+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For the missing value you can just do

```
df.fillna(0, subset=['sales'])
```

For the 3 months average, you can find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824339/7306659), just be careful to parse correctly timestamp and change the window starting day to -90

UPDATE

This code should do the job you look for

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400
w = (Window.orderBy(f.col("timestampGMT").cast('long')).rangeBetween(-days(90), 0))

missings_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([ ('A', 'pharma', '1/6/2019', 0)], ['product', 'specialty', 'date', 'sales'])

df = (df
      .union(missings_df) # adding missing row
      .withColumn('timestampGMT', f.to_date('date', 'd/M/yyyy').cast('timestamp')) # cast to timestamp
      .withColumn('rolling_average', f.avg("sales").over(w)) # rolling average on 90 days
     )
```

Comment: I want add another row of data which has date was missing in the input . In the above input 1/6/2019 is missed . I will had the data which product A ,speciality pharma ,date 1/6/2019 and sales value is zero .

Comment: then check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692858/7306659