# duplicating records between date gaps within a selected time interval in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rolling-computation

I have a PySpark dataframe that keeps track of changes that occur in a product's price and status over months. This means that a new row is created only when a change occurred (in either status or price) compared to the previous month, like in the dummy data below

```
    ----------------------------------------
    |product_id| status    | price| month  |
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | available | 5    | 2019-10|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | available | 8    | 2020-08|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | limited   | 8    | 2020-10|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 1    | 2020-09|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 3    | 2020-10|
    ----------------------------------------
```

I would like to create a dataframe that shows the values for each of the last 6 months. This means that I need to duplicate the records whenever there is a gap in the above dataframe. For example, if the last 6 months are 2020-07, 2020-08, ... 2020-12, then the result for the above dataframe should be

```
    ----------------------------------------
    |product_id| status    | price| month  |
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | available | 5    | 2020-07|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | available | 8    | 2020-08|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | available | 8    | 2020-09|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | limited   | 8    | 2020-10|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | limited   | 8    | 2020-11|
    ----------------------------------------
    |1         | limited   | 8    | 2020-12|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 1    | 2020-09|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 3    | 2020-10|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 3    | 2020-11|
    ----------------------------------------
    |2         | limited   | 3    | 2020-12|
    ----------------------------------------
```

Notice that for product_id = 1 there was an older record from 2019-10 that was propagated until 2020-08 and then trimmed, whereas for product_id = 2 there were no records prior to 2020-09 and thus the months 2020-07, 2020-08 were not filled for it (as the product did not exist prior to 2020-09).

Since the dataframe consists of millions of records, a "brute-force" solution using for loops and checking for each product_id is rather slow. It seems that it should be possible to solve this using window functions, by creating another column next_month and then filling in the gaps based on that column, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: if you can use spark 2.4+, use transform + sequence, see a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64493392/9510729)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Respect to the **@jxc** comment, I have prepared the answer for this use case.

Following is the code snippet.

1. Import the spark SQL functions

   `from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window`
2. Prepare the sample data

```
    simpleData = ((1,"Available",5,"2020-07"),                                                              
    (1,"Available",8,"2020-08"),                                           
    (1,"Limited",8,"2020-12"),                                           
    (2,"Limited",1,"2020-09"),                                          
    (2,"Limited",3,"2020-12")
    )

    
    columns= ["product_id", "status", "price", "month"]
```

3. Creating dataframe of sample data

   `df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)`
4. Add date column in dataframe to get proper formatted date

```
    df0 = df.withColumn("date",F.to_date('month','yyyy-MM'))

    df0.show()

    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+                                          
    |product_id|   status|price|  month|      date|                                               
    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+                                                
    |         1|Available|    5|2020-07|2020-07-01|                                                 
    |         1|Available|    8|2020-08|2020-08-01|                                                
    |         1|  Limited|    8|2020-12|2020-12-01|                                                
    |         2|  Limited|    1|2020-09|2020-09-01|                                                
    |         2|  Limited|    3|2020-12|2020-12-01|                                                
    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+
```

5. Creating WinSpec w1 and use Window aggregate function lead to find the next date over(w1), convert it to the previous months to set up date sequences:

```
    w1 = Window.partitionBy('product_id').orderBy('date')
    df1 = df0.withColumn('end_date',F.coalesce(F.add_months(F.lead('date').over(w1),-1),'date'))
    df1.show()

    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+----------+                                                                  
    |product_id|   status|price|  month|      date|  end_date|                                                      
    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+----------+                                              
    |         1|Available|    5|2020-07|2020-07-01|2020-07-01|                                                      
    |         1|Available|    8|2020-08|2020-08-01|2020-11-01|                                                            
    |         1|  Limited|    8|2020-12|2020-12-01|2020-12-01|                                                                     
    |         2|  Limited|    1|2020-09|2020-09-01|2020-11-01|                                                                            
    |         2|  Limited|    3|2020-12|2020-12-01|2020-12-01|                                                                                   
    +----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```

6. Using months_between(end_date, date) to calculate # of months between two dates, and use transform function to iterate through sequence(0, #months), create a named_struct with date=add_months(date,i) and price=IF(i=0,price,price), use inline_outer to explode the array of structs.

```
    df2 = df1.selectExpr("product_id", "status", inline_outer( transform( sequence(0,int(months_between(end_date, date)),1), i -> (add_months(date,i) as date, IF(i=0,price,price) as price) ) ) )

    df2.show()

    +----------+---------+----------+-----+                                                    
    |product_id|   status|      date|price|                                                             
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+                                                              
    |         1|Available|2020-07-01|    5|                                                              
    |         1|Available|2020-08-01|    8|                                                  
    |         1|Available|2020-09-01|    8|                                                           
    |         1|Available|2020-10-01|    8|                                                             
    |         1|Available|2020-11-01|    8|                                                                 
    |         1|  Limited|2020-12-01|    8|                                                                
    |         2|  Limited|2020-09-01|    1|                                                                                 
    |         2|  Limited|2020-10-01|    1|                                                    
    |         2|  Limited|2020-11-01|    1|                                                                          
    |         2|  Limited|2020-12-01|    3|                                                          
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+
```

7. Partitioning the dataframe on `product_id` and adding a rank column in `df3` to get row number for each row. Then, Storing the maximum of `rank` column value with new column `max_rank` for each `product_id` and storing `max_rank` in to `df4`

```
    w2 = Window.partitionBy('product_id').orderBy('date')                                                            
    df3 = df2.withColumn('rank',F.row_number().over(w2))                                                                 
    Schema: DataFrame[product_id: bigint, status: string, date: date, price: bigint, rank: int]
    df3.show()
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+
    |product_id|   status|      date|price|rank|
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+
    |         1|Available|2020-07-01|    5|   1|
    |         1|Available|2020-08-01|    8|   2|
    |         1|Available|2020-09-01|    8|   3|
    |         1|Available|2020-10-01|    8|   4|
    |         1|Available|2020-11-01|    8|   5|
    |         1|  Limited|2020-12-01|    8|   6|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-09-01|    1|   1|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-10-01|    1|   2|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-11-01|    1|   3|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-12-01|    3|   4|
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+ 

                                                                                                           
    df4 = df3.groupBy("product_id").agg(F.max('rank').alias('max_rank'))                                                           
    Schema: DataFrame[product_id: bigint, max_rank: int]
    df4.show()
    +----------+--------+
    |product_id|max_rank|
    +----------+--------+
    |         1|       6|
    |         2|       4|
    +----------+--------+
```

8. Joining `df3` and `df4` dataframes on `product_id` get `max_rank`

```
    df5 = df3.join(df4,df3.product_id == df4.product_id,"inner") \
             .select(df3.product_id,df3.status,df3.date,df3.price,df3.rank,df4.max_rank)                                                                                          
    Schema: DataFrame[product_id: bigint, status: string, date: date, price: bigint, rank: int, max_rank: int]
    df5.show()
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+--------+
    |product_id|   status|      date|price|rank|max_rank|
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+--------+
    |         1|Available|2020-07-01|    5|   1|       6|
    |         1|Available|2020-08-01|    8|   2|       6|
    |         1|Available|2020-09-01|    8|   3|       6|
    |         1|Available|2020-10-01|    8|   4|       6|
    |         1|Available|2020-11-01|    8|   5|       6|
    |         1|  Limited|2020-12-01|    8|   6|       6|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-09-01|    1|   1|       4|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-10-01|    1|   2|       4|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-11-01|    1|   3|       4|
    |         2|  Limited|2020-12-01|    3|   4|       4|
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+----+--------+
```

9. Then finally filtering the `df5` dataframe using `between` function to get the latest 6 months data.

```
    FinalResultDF = df5.filter(F.col('rank') \                                      
                         .between(F.when((F.col('max_rank') > 5),(F.col('max_rank')-6)).otherwise(0),F.col('max_rank'))) \
                         .select(df5.product_id,df5.status,df5.date,df5.price)

    FinalResultDF.show(truncate=False)
```

```
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+                                               
    |product_id|status   |date      |price|                                                
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+                                                               
    |1         |Available|2020-07-01|5    |                                                                                
    |1         |Available|2020-08-01|8    |                                                                                          
    |1         |Available|2020-09-01|8    |                                                                                                           
    |1         |Available|2020-10-01|8    |                                                                                                             
    |1         |Available|2020-11-01|8    |                                                                                                               
    |1         |Limited  |2020-12-01|8    |                                                                                                                     
    |2         |Limited  |2020-09-01|1    |                                                                                                                     
    |2         |Limited  |2020-10-01|1    |                                                                                                                        
    |2         |Limited  |2020-11-01|1    |                                                                                                                      
    |2         |Limited  |2020-12-01|3    |                                                                                                         
    +----------+---------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using spark-sql:

Given input dataframe:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  1 c1,   'available' c2, 5 c3,   '2019-10' c4  union all
 select  1 c1,   'available' c2, 8 c3,   '2020-08' c4  union all
 select  1 c1,   'limited' c2, 8 c3,   '2020-10' c4  union all
 select  2 c1,   'limited' c2, 1 c3,   '2020-09' c4  union all
 select  2 c1,   'limited' c2, 3 c3,   '2020-10' c4 
  )  select   c1  product_id,   c2   status    ,   c3   price,   c4  month      from t1
""")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df.show(false)

+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|product_id|status   |price|month  |
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|1         |available|5    |2019-10|
|1         |available|8    |2020-08|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-10|
|2         |limited  |1    |2020-09|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-10|
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Filter on the date window i.e 6 months from 2020-07 to 2020-12 and store them in df1

```
val df1 = spark.sql("""
select * from df where month > '2020-07' and month < '2020-12' 
""")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df1.show(false)

+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|product_id|status   |price|month  |
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|1         |available|8    |2020-08|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-10|
|2         |limited  |1    |2020-09|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-10|
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Lower boundary - Get the maximum when the month <='2020-07'. Overwrite the month as '2020-07'

```
val df2 = spark.sql("""
select product_id, status, price, '2020-07' month from df  where (product_id,month) in 
( select product_id, max(month) from df where month <= '2020-07' group by 1 ) 
""")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
df2.show(false)

+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|product_id|status   |price|month  |
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|1         |available|5    |2020-07|
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Upper boundary - Get the maximum using <='2020-12'. Overwrite the month as '2020-12'

```
val df3 = spark.sql("""
select product_id, status, price, '2020-12' month from df where (product_id, month) in  
( select product_id, max(month) from df where month <= '2020-12' group by 1 ) 
""")
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("df3")
df3.show(false)

+----------+-------+-----+-------+
|product_id|status |price|month  |
+----------+-------+-----+-------+
|1         |limited|8    |2020-12|
|2         |limited|3    |2020-12|
+----------+-------+-----+-------+
```

Now union all the 3 and store it in df4

```
val df4 = spark.sql("""
select  product_id, status, price,  month from df1  union all 
select  product_id, status, price,  month from df2  union all 
select  product_id, status, price,  month from df3
order by product_id, month
""")
df4.createOrReplaceTempView("df4")
df4.show(false)

+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|product_id|status   |price|month  |
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
|1         |available|5    |2020-07|
|1         |available|8    |2020-08|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-10|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-12|
|2         |limited  |1    |2020-09|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-10|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-12|
+----------+---------+-----+-------+
```

**Result:**
Use sequence(date1,date2, interval 1 month) to generate date array for the missing months.
Explode the array and you get the results.

```
spark.sql("""
select product_id, status, price, month, explode(dt) res_month from 
(
select t1.*, 
case when months_between(lm||'-01',month||'-01')=1.0 then array(month||'-01')
     when month='2020-12' then array(month||'-01')
     else sequence(to_date(month||'-01'), add_months(to_date(lm||'-01'),-1), interval 1 month ) 
end dt 
     from (
            select product_id, status, price, month, 
            lead(month) over(partition by product_id order by month) lm 
            from df4 
          ) t1 
    ) t2 
  order by product_id, res_month
""")
.show(false)

+----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+
|product_id|status   |price|month  |res_month |
+----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+
|1         |available|5    |2020-07|2020-07-01|
|1         |available|8    |2020-08|2020-08-01|
|1         |available|8    |2020-08|2020-09-01|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-10|2020-10-01|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-10|2020-11-01|
|1         |limited  |8    |2020-12|2020-12-01|
|2         |limited  |1    |2020-09|2020-09-01|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-10|2020-10-01|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-10|2020-11-01|
|2         |limited  |3    |2020-12|2020-12-01|
+----------+---------+-----+-------+----------+
```